# Joining Tables With Zend Framework PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am relatively new to the Zend Framework.

I understand the usage of Zend_Table and can obtain data using the Zend functions from the table associated with that class.

For example I have a video table and in another table I have the association between the video and what category it is in.

Im a little stumped how to active a select like the following within the framework:

SELECT * FROM `video`,`category` WHERE `category`.`category_id` = 3 AND `video`.`id` = `category`.`video_id`

Any advice would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$db->select()->from('video')->joinInner('category','video.id = category.video_id')->where('category.category_id = ?',3)
```

BTW: It looks like you have wrong db design. You should have category_id in your video table (if 1 video -> 1 category) or have a connection table (M:N), but it seems wrong to have video id stored in category.

Comment: just a short fyi.

$sql = $this->getDbTable()->select()->where('group_id = ?', $group_id)->joinInner('category','video.id = category.video_id')->where('category.category_id = ?',3);

$result = $this->getDbTable()->fetchRow($sql);

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`Zend_Db_Select`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html):

```
    $select = $this->db->select()->from(array('v' => 'video'))
                   ->join(array('c' => 'category'),'v.id = c.video_id')
                   ->where('c.category_id = ?', 3);
    print_r($select->__toString());
```

Output:

```
SELECT `v`.*, `c`.* FROM `video` AS `v` INNER JOIN `category` AS `c` ON v.id = c.video_id WHERE (c.category_id = 3)
```

Comment: how would you read columns from the category table in this example. is it expected that the Zend_Db_Table_Abstract would define the referenceMap or can i pass an array of specific category column names to read?