# PHP / Zend Framework: Which object would handle a complex table join?

Tags: php, zend-framework, join, model

I think one of the more difficult concepts to understand in the Zend Framework is how the Table Data Gateway pattern is supposed to handle multi-table joins. Most of the suggestions I've seen claim that you simply handle the joins using a $db->select()...

[Zend DB Select with multiple table joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884313/zend-db-select-with-multiple-table-joins) 
[Joining Tables With Zend Framework PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199383/joining-tables-with-zend-framework-php) 
[Joining tables wthin a model in Zend Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299647/joining-tables-wthin-a-model-in-zend-php)
[Zend Framework Db Select Join table help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270125/zend-framework-db-select-join-table-help)
[Zend DB Select with multiple table joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884313/zend-db-select-with-multiple-table-joins)

**My question is: Which object is best suited to handle this kind of multi-table select statement?** I feel like putting it in the model would break the 1-1 Table Data Gateway pattern between the class and the db table. Yet putting it in the controller seems wrong because why would a controller handle a SQL statement? Anyway, I feel like ZF makes handling datasets from multiple tables more difficult than it needs to be. Any help you can provide is great...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By [definition](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html), TableData Gateway handles one table only.

ZF enforces this definition with an integrity check on Zend_Db_Table_Selects. However, the integrity check can be disabled and then you can do joins. Just create a method inside your table class to do the Join via the select object like this:

```
public function findByIdAndJoinFoo($id)
{
   $select = $this->select();
   $select->setIntegrityCheck(false) // allows joins
          ->from($this)
          ->join('foo', 'foo.id = bar.foo_id');

   return $this->fetchAll($select);
}
```

If you want to stick to the definition, you you can use [some sort of Service Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436461/how-to-change-zend-db-table-name-within-a-model-to-insert-in-multiple-tables/2436603#2436603) or [DataMapper](http://github.com/bradley-holt/postr/blob/master/application/models/EntryMapper.php) that knows how to handle multiple tables. These sit between the Db classes and the Controllers.

Another alternative is not to use Joins but [table relationships](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html) and then lazy load dependent rowsets as needed. Of course, that's not Joins then, but multiple queries.

And finally, you can still just use [Zend_Db_Statement and craft your SQL by hand](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html):

```
  $stmt = $db->query(
              'SELECT * FROM bugs WHERE reported_by = ? AND bug_status = ?',
              array('goofy', 'FIXED'));
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon, this is very informative but still has me confused. It seems strange to break the TableData Gateway definition every time you need to perform a join, which is what a RDBMS does so well. But then introducing a whole service layer adds complexity to what seems like a simple issue. It seems like the way to go is with a hand crafted statement, but where's the best place to put it? Again, I'd want it to be somewhere in the model but I don't see it being in a method on a particular gateway class since the statement would span multiple tables.

Comment: @Thomas It seems simple, but it isn't. You could create Views in your DB or have TDGs that simulate Views. If you do it in the TDG, insertion will be difficult. TDG works nicely as long as your domain objects map 1:1 to the underlying database. But they rarely do (impedance mismatch), so it's not uncommon to use some sort of ORM or other ServiceLayer (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) that mediates between the persistence layer and the domain objects in your model.